# How to implement the DS-digital font in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts

I am creating a calculator application in which i have to use the DS-Digital font. I have downloaded the DS-Digital.ttf font file, but i am not getting how can i use this and implement this in my application programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer - this should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 12):

1) Copy the font file into the resources of your project. (Just drag it into the 'supporting files or whatever directory you use').

2) In your info.plist file enter the filename of the font file for key "Fonts Provided by the Application" - like in the picture below (I use two versions of the font, you must enter your font file name (DS-DIGI.TTF))

[image: my example]

3) In places you want to use the font do `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7" size: yoursize]`

example:

```
someuilabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7" size: yoursize];
```

*** EDIT: Note that the font has some confusing names. You can list all fonts installed on the phone with

```
// List all fonts on iPhone
  NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
  NSArray *fontNames;
  NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
  for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
  {
      NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
      fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
          [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
          [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
      for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
      {
          NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
      }
      [fontNames release];
  }
  [familyNames release];
```

And find the exact name of the font you want.

Answer (score 2):

Add this font to your xcode project and then add **Fonts provided by application** key in info.plist and specify **DS-Digital.ttf** to its value. Then you can use it by code.

```
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"DS-Digital" size:20.0];
```

Comment: This code is not helpful for me. Can you please suggest some another code.The font file i have downloaded is DS-DIGI.TTF,how can i use this.

Comment: I want to use the DS-DIGI font for my whole application for the textfield and labels,when user feed the input through keypad,Can anyone tell me the whole procedure for it?

Comment: I have given you the whole procedure in my answer. What don't you understand?
You need to set the font of every label/textfield etc the way i do it in my example (someuilabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7" size: yoursize];)

Comment: @rinkuyadav Are you providing correct  name in your info.plist